# Using boost::future with continuations and boost::when_all

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, future, continuations

I would like to use `boost::future` with continuations and `boost::when_all` / `boost::when_any`.

Boost *trunk* - not 1.55 - includes implementations for the latter (modeled after the proposal [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3634.pdf), upcoming for C++14/17 and Boost 1.56).

[This](https://gist.github.com/oberstet) is what I have (and **it does not compile**):

```
#include <iostream>

#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_WHEN_ALL_WHEN_ANY
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
   future<int> f1 = async([]() { return 1; });
   future<int> f2 = async([]() { return 2; });

   auto f3 = when_all(f1, f2);

   f3.then([](decltype(f3)) {
      std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
   });

   f3.get();
}
```

Clang 3.4 bails out with a [this](https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9783364) - here is an excerpt:

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1685:31: error: call to deleted constructor of 'boost::future<int>'
::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

Am I doing it wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I think you need to `get` the `future` returned from `then` instead of `f3`, i.e., `auto f4 = f3.then(...); f4.get();`

Comment: Does not help :( https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9785088

Comment: `when_all` takes iterators if I read the source code I found correctly. You're not using iterators. Did you try putting the futures in a vector and calling `when_all(vec.begin(), vec.end())` instead?

Comment: Exactly the same issue ("call to deleted constructor") with https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9785331 Also, at least the proposal linked (the paper) mentions 2 overloaded versions of `when_all` .. one taking positional args, the other iterators.

Comment: You are passing futures to `when_all` by value, which wants to copy them. Since futures are move-only, the universe explodes. Move them: `auto f3 = when_all(std::move(f1), std::move(f2));` or omit the named temporaries: `auto f = when_all(async([]{return 1;}), async([]{return 2;}));` Also, I believe [N3857](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf) is the most recent revision of this proposal.

Comment: Hehehe. You're making me do some reading. Thanks for that. No time to do it now though :(

Comment: [gist.github.com/oberstet/9785331](https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9785331) has the same problem because the `std::vector` constructor from `std::intializer_list` is trying to copy the futures.

Comment: @Casey That does the trick! This works: https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9785686 - If you post an answer, I accept! I was reading the proposal paper, and the sample code there has bugs wrt to this (as far as I understand).

Comment: @oberstet Yeah, I noticed the erroneous example, and [have reported it in the (hopefully) appropriate place](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=&pli=1#!topic/std-proposals/gltCbLgrkT0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `when_all` may only be called with rvalue `future` or `shared_future`. From [N3857](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf):

> ```
> template <typename... T> 
> see below when_all(T&&... futures);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `T` is of type `future<R>` or `shared_future<R>`.

Thanks to the reference-collapsing rules, passing an lvalue results in `T` being deduced to `future<T>&` in violation of the stated requirement. The boost implementation doesn't check this precondition so you get an error deep in the template code where what should be a move of an rvalue future turns into an attempted copy of an lvalue future.

You need to either move the futures into the `when_all` parameters:

```
auto f3 = when_all(std::move(f1), std::move(f2));
```

or avoid naming them in the first place:

```
auto f = when_all(async([]{return 1;}),
                  async([]{return 2;}));
```

Also, you must `get` the future returned from `then` instead of the intermediate future:

```
auto done = f.then([](decltype(f)) {
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
});

done.get();
```

since the future upon which you call `then` is moved into the parameter of the continuation. From the description of `then` in N3857:

> Postcondition:
>
> - The `future` object is moved to the parameter of the continuation function
> - `valid() == false` on original `future` object immediately after it returns

Per 30.6.6 [futures.unique_future]/3:

> The effect of calling any member function other than the destructor, the move-assignment operator, or `valid` on a `future` object for which `valid() == false` is undefined.

You could avoid most of these issues in c++14 by avoiding naming the futures at all:

```
when_all(
  async([]{return 1;}),
  async([]{return 2;})
).then([](auto&) {
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}).get();
```

Comment: Only thing I am wondering is why I am allowed to move a future twice .. see the code linked right above. It moves `f2` into `when_all` resulting in `f12`, and second time into `when_all` that results in `f23`. Could you explain why that is allowed / works? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @oberstet A moved-from object isn't invalid, it is in a "valid but unspecified state." You can move from objects repeatedly, but the result of doing so is implementation-defined.

Comment: @oberstet Minor correction to the above, which is generally true of standard library objects unless specified otherwise: from 30.6.6 [futures.unique_future]/3 "The effect of calling any member function other than the destructor, the move-assignment operator, or `valid` on a `future` object for which `valid() == false` is undefined."

Comment: Thanks alot! This is invaluable .. was fighting all this for 2 hours.

Comment: @oberstet Fixed the answer: I was correct about the solution, but not precisely correct about the problem.

Comment: Using `auto&` as a parameter to `.then` does not even work with clang 3.4 and `-std=c++1y` (`error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype`). Then Boost trunk has issues with `c++1y` as well (`/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:156:9: error: no member named 'gets' in the global namespace`). Which compiler do you use?

Comment: @oberstet I *didn't* attempt to compile the C++14 version since I don't have access to both Clang and Boost trunk on the same platform. I do note that [Clang r198621 on Coliru compiles the generic lambda correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e9a21daee5e1e00).

Comment: Thanks for replying! I guess it's a feature of clang 3.5. It seems to be handy though .. looking forward.

Comment: @oberstet mentioned that it can't compile. Actually, the code is incorrect, it should be `then([](auto&&)` instead of `then([](auto&)`. This is due to the reference collapsing that Scott Meyers talked about.