# Cannot find std::experimental::when_any

Tags: c++, visual-studio, future

I am trying to use `std::experimental::when_any` and `std::experimental::when_all` which according to [Anthony Williams](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Concurrency-Action-Second/dp/B082MSBZ68/ref=sr_1_1?adgrpid=48775698450&gclid=Cj0KCQiAw9qOBhC-ARIsAG-rdn7mu4e4qDn-YSBkqpz1lKiZmjLcnjRb2GvxfAFtiUg5w4isZp1fxyYaArXxEALw_wcB&hvadid=259087860624&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1006993&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=13877709769642696201&hvtargid=kwd-299433375070&hydadcr=17608_1817743&keywords=concurrency%20in%20action&qid=1641465262&sr=8-1) are in <experimental/future> header.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (same is for 2019) and cannot find this header/functions neither under C++17 standard nor under C++20 standard configurations.

Can someone please help to reach this functions in VS?

Comment: `experimental` is probably nothing to rely on for portability. Please check out cppreference.com (and bookmark it) to see something that's updated regularly.

Comment: I think Boost does have `when_any`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22664296/using-boostfuture-with-continuations-and-boostwhen-all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The experimental headers are not part of the standard. An implementation *may* provide them, but is not required to.

They are defined for features that the C++ committee is working on incorporating into a future standard.

Neither Visual Studio 2019 nor 2022 provide `<experimental/future>`